# Android Market statistics frozen nearly month, what's going on?

Tags: android, statistics, google-play

I have several applications in Android Market and 2 or 3 weeks ago I have noticed that statistics still the same. Just before that I have had several hundreds downloads per week. For sure I reported issue to Google guys, but nothing except standard - we're investigating problem...

Probably anyone knows, what's going on? Are there anyone who's experiencing similar troubles?

Comment: Nobody likes your app. That simple. :) Nah i'm joking. +1 Great question. There is a couple of guys having the same problem as you are, but they called google. You should try that. http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=62421154b5203024&hl=en

Comment: Now it works, statistics were frozen but there were downloads - seems to be Google fixed issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now it works, statistics were frozen but there were downloads - seems to be Google fixed issue.